# JVM consumes all CPU, most threads as BLOCKED. JVM bug?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Last night, a server (JBoss 5.1GA, Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02), 
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, running in a Linux VM on VMWare) suddenly started to use 100% CPU. The app is a fairly typical J2EE business app running Seam, nothing particular about it. The load was extremely low at that time.

I managed to get a thread dump before the process was killed and restarted (the app had to be available). JStack had an exception in its deadlock detection; apart from that most threads were in BLOCKED.

Is this a JVM bug? I haven't seen it before. After restart everything was ok, like in the several months since the application has been used on that server (with periodic updates).

Thanks for any suggestions.

A slightly edited thread dump (to fit within SO's post size limit) is below. I removed a few identical threads (from the various thread pools inside JBoss/Seam) and left only the top lines from the stack traces.

**EDIT: full thread dump** at http://pastie.org/1083984

```
[~]$ jstack -F 13553
Attaching to process ID 13553, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 11.3-b02
Deadlock Detection:

java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.InstanceKlass.computeSubtypeOf(InstanceKlass.java:426)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Klass.isSubtypeOf(Klass.java:137)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Oop.isA(Oop.java:92)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:93)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:39)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:52)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)
Can't print deadlocks:null
Thread 26208: (state = BLOCKED)


Thread 25250: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 25249: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 21240: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 21140: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 21139: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 21138: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19380: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19377: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19361: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19343: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 19317: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 18995: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 18986: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 17659: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 17658: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 17653: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 17631: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14977: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14796: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14609: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14437: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14248: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 14232: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.util.Arrays.copyOf(char[], int) @bci=1, line=2882 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(int) @bci=33, line=100 (Compiled frame)

Thread 14040: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=7, line=384 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13858: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=116 (Compiled frame)

Thread 13815: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)

 Thread 13814: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13813: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.await() @bci=8, line=416 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 13812: (state = BLOCKED)
Error occurred during stack walking:
sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.AssertionFailure: range check
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.Assert.that(Assert.java:32)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.RegisterMap.<init>(RegisterMap.java:109)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86RegisterMap.<init>(X86RegisterMap.java:39)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.x86.X86RegisterMap.clone(X86RegisterMap.java:43)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.<init>(VFrame.java:37)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaVFrame.<init>(JavaVFrame.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.CompiledVFrame.<init>(CompiledVFrame.java:43)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.newVFrame(VFrame.java:77)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.sender(VFrame.java:129)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VFrame.javaSender(VFrame.java:146)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.JavaThread.getLastJavaVFrameDbg(JavaThread.java:231)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:76)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:118)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:84)


Thread 13811: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13810: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13809: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClientConsumer.getMessage(long) @bci=71, line=866 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13808: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.jboss.jms.client.container.ClientConsumer.getMessage(long) @bci=71, line=866 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13807: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl$LifeThread.run() @bci=11, line=866 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13806: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13805: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13804: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=509 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13803: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=509 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13802: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(char[], int, int) @bci=40, line=3209 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.String.<init>(char[], int, int) @bci=65, line=216 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.StringBuffer.toString() @bci=13, line=585 (Compiled frame)
 - org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=68, line=506 (Compiled frame)

Thread 13784: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - org.jboss.el.util.ReferenceCache$ReferenceQueueRunner.run() @bci=1, line=159 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13753: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.jboss.ejb3.cache.simple.SimpleStatefulCache$SessionTimeoutTask.block() @bci=11, line=210 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13752: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.IdleRemover$IdleRemoverRunnable.run() @bci=31, line=167 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13749: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run() @bci=209, line=284 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13734: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop() @bci=201, line=509 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13701: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.lang.Object) @bci=14, line=158 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13700: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.jboss.console.plugins.AOPLister$RefreshPoller.run() @bci=41, line=898 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13699: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Thread.sleep(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run() @bci=22, line=1590 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=619 (Interpreted frame)


Thread 13698: (state = IN_NATIVE)
 - java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(java.net.SocketImpl) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13678: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) @bci=20, line=198 (Interpreted frame)

Thread 13554: (state = BLOCKED)

Thread 13560: (state = BLOCKED)

Thread 13559: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(long) @bci=44, line=116 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove() @bci=2, line=132 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run() @bci=3, line=159 (Compiled frame)


Thread 13558: (state = BLOCKED)
 - java.lang.Object.wait(long) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Object.wait() @bci=2, line=485 (Compiled frame)
 - java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run() @bci=46, line=116 (Compiled frame)
```

Comment: I'd like to see the complete stack trace for the unique blocked threads.  Maybe you can repost the entire dump somewhere without the SO limitation?

Comment: I put it on pastie and updated the question with the link (http://pastie.org/1083984)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possibility is that you ran out of heap space. If you run out of heap space the JVM will start to burn up the CPU at a tremendous rate doing frantic garbage collection.

Comment: I had the same problem and it was in fact the heap space that was too small. If you use jmap, you can figure out if the heap space is actually your problem. If you run `jmap -heap <process id>` from the command line, the output will show you the percentage of used heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is a disk or RAM error. These are very rare especially if you are using ECC RAM, SAS or SCSI which contain error correction on data transfer. But it could happen!

I've read about some really weird bugs seen by IBM and Sun kernel engineers doing support for big enterprises that they can only blame on stuff like this.

This doesn't help you much, other than letting you know that you may never discover the real reason it happened and it may never happen again for years. :)